# Error submitting jobs on a condor cluster with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to sumbit some snakemake jobs to a condor cluster with the following command.

```
snakemake -f TestJob --cluster-config cluster.json -j 30 --cluster condor_submit
```

where the TestJob rule is specified in the SnakeFile

```py
rule TestJob:
    input:
    output: "test.txt"
    shell:
        "touch test.txt;"
```

and the cluster-configuration file is the following:

```
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "output"    : "workdir/logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error"     : "workdir/logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err",
        "log"       : "workdir/logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.log"
    },

}
```

When I do this I obtain the following error:

```sh
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 30
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   TestJob
    1

[Mon Jul  1 11:18:04 2019]
rule TestJob:
    output: test.txt
    jobid: 0


ERROR: on Line 11 of submit file: 

ERROR: Failed to parse command file (line 11).
Error submitting jobscript (exit code 1):
Submitting job(s)
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Has anyone any idea of what might be happening? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake should write the string under the `shell` directive to a temporary file and pass that file to `condor_submit` as a command argument. I.e., in your case the temp file would contain only the line `touch test.txt;` and then snakemake would execute `condor_submit temp.sh`.

So, what happens if you actually write a file with the only line `touch test.txt;` and then do `condor_submit temp.sh`? Just a wild guess as I'm not familiar with condor...

(However, the error message says `ERROR: on Line 11 of submit file:` so maybe the submitted file has more than 1 line)

Comment: Do you know any way of accessing directly to that submission file? that would be faster to debug

Comment: Not sure where the submission file is... However, the test I suggest should be straightforward. Also, try simplifying even more your snakemake execution by removing `--cluster-config cluster.json`